# How to download all transcripts from seeking alpha

Tags: python, web, download, web-crawler

Is there some way to automatically download all the transcripts from the SA website?

http://seekingalpha.com/earnings/earnings-call-transcripts

I tried using the http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ python code but I get the following error:

```
earnings_call_transcripts_2 = newspaper.build('http://seekingalpha.com/earnings/earnings-call-transcripts', memoize_articles=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/parsers.py", line 67, in fromstring
    cls.doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 867, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 752, in document_fromstring
    value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:77697)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116494)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1700, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:115040)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1040, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:109165)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103404)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105058)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:104143)
  File "<string>", line None
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: line 295: b"htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'"
[Source parse ERR] http://seekingalpha.com/earnings/earnings-call-transcripts
```

Comment: Post the whole error.  You stopped before it got to the actual error part.

Comment: i edited my original post please see the whole error

Comment: Could you find any solution for the problem?

Comment: It is possible that they have detected that you are a bot/scraper, and in this case they serve you up a captcha page instead which then causes all sorts of errors.  I have had this happen to me in the past.  You need to find out what you are actually retrieving.